# Merge Tables from different Databases

Tags: mysql, database

I wanna merge 3 tables (2 from the same DB, one from another DB)
Each include emails.

Goal is to create ONE List of 'unique" emails (no double email)

I tried first only from one DB:

```
SELECT email FROM db1.table1 group by email 
UNION ALL
SELECT email FROM db1.table2 group by email
```

works fine.

In the moment I add the table from the other DB

```
SELECT email FROM db1.table1 group by email 
UNION ALL
SELECT email FROM db1.table2 group by email 
UNION ALL
SELECT email FROM db2.table1 group by email
```

I get

> 1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

any help how to reach my goal.
(i tried via PHP, line by line comparing if email is already listed in the new db, by each table 200k emails, it needs HOURS)

UPDATE:
thanks for comment.

1#   UNION and not UNION ALL to get UNIQUE Emails.
2#   SELECT email COLLATE utf8_general_ci FROM db1.table1 group by email

by COLLATE I dont get this error anymore.

Seems to work now. I will check a bit further and than close this Question.
Thank you

Comment: First thing, to get the unique email use the Union not Union all

Answer (score 0):

As error state, there should be different 'collations'  of your columns

```
select collation(email) from db1.table1
select collation(email) from db2.table1
```

If both queries return the different value then you need to the `collation` of one column.

Sample Query to convert it as below:

```
SELECT email FROM db1.table1 group by email 
UNION
SELECT email FROM db1.table2 group by email 
UNION
SELECT 
  email COLLATE utf8_general_ci
FROM db2.table1 group by email
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a multi-step process?

To get unique emails you could start by putting everything in one table. You don't even need a query for this, you could just export, modify and import the rows with any database tool. After that you could remove duplicates like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE allEmails ADD UNIQUE (email)
```

However this will probably be slow, especially if `email` is a TEXT and has no index. To get around this you could make a hash for each email. Create a column called `hash`:

```
ALTER TABLE allEmails ADD hash VARCHAR(35), ADD INDEX (`hash`)
```

and populate it with:

```
UPDATE allEmails SET hash = MD5(email);
```

Now you can take advantage of the shorter hash with an index like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE allEmails ADD UNIQUE (hash)
```

You can delete the hash column after that. This should now be a process without significant bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, for me worked:

1# UNION and not UNION ALL to get UNIQUE Emails.

2# SELECT email COLLATE utf8_general_ci FROM db1.table1 group by email